# How to change email address to reply to in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have method for sending emails:

```
public static void sendMail(InternetAddress[] to, InternetAddress[] cc, InternetAddress[] bcc, String subject, String body, String priority, String type) throws MessagingException {
    String host = "127.0.0.1";

    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

    Session session = Session.getInstance(properties);

    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.addHeader("X-Priority", priority);
    msg.setFrom("noreply@mydomain.com");
    msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);

    if (cc != null) {
        msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, cc);
    }

    if (bcc != null) {
        msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, bcc);
    }

    if (type == null) {
        msg.setText(body);
    } else {
        msg.setText(body, "utf-8", type);
    }

    Transport.send(msg);
}
```

and I want that, if some user replies to such email, his email will be redirected to some other email (e.g. support@mydomain.com).

Comment: This might help: https://coderanch.com/t/274415/java/set-Return-Path-email-address#2823152

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try **msg.setReplyTo(replyTo);** Please note that replyTo is not same as **From Address**

Answer (score 0):

Set the "envelope from" address, either by setting the property [`mail.smtp.from`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html#mail.smtp.from), or by using the [SMTPMessage.setEnvelopeFrom](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPMessage.html#setEnvelopeFrom-java.lang.String-) method.